# proxy_pass not support # in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am new to nginx and I am trying to create clean URL pattern where if I use below URL on browser `"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:61001/employee"` then it should route to `"http://localhost:8080/emp/#/details"`. But unfortunately I am getting 404 error on browser. Even though my application is up and running. # (special character) having some issue in nginx. can someone help me here.

Below my configuration:

```
location /employee {proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/emp/#/details;
}
```

Getting 404 error on browser

This is my full server config:

```
server { 
  listen 8081;
  server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
  location / { root html; index index.html index.htm; }
  location /employee { proxy_pass localhost:8080/emp/#/details; }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html { root html; } 
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post code in comments

Comment: @ravisharma what about write it like this ? `http://localhost:8080/emp/%23/details`

Comment: @barbsan I have tried pasting in code section but some how editor not able to vlidate my code. So i had to paste in comment section to give zest of it. Thank you fo rthe suggestion.

Comment: @MostafaHussein I tried using %23 instead of # but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are listening on port 8081 change it to 80.

```
server { 
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
  location / { root html; index index.html index.htm; }
  location /employee { proxy_pass localhost:8080/emp/#/details; }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html { root html; } 
}
```